# How do I turn on Detailed Logging?

Tags: logging

The book tells about the advantages of Detailed Logging at length, but I don't see how to turn it on.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this page yet, Adam? https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers

Comment: Beware of the performance implications, turning on logging won't hit performance until you come to use the UI to look at a contact's log - then be prepared to wait. The performance trade is reasonable but it's a long wait.

Answer (score 4):

Logging can be turned on via Administer > System Settings > Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.).

You will find the relevant page on the Drupal demo site [here](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1)

(NB, i am using the link to the master to give the url longevity)

You will also find explanation in the manual [here](https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/advanced-configuration/logging/)

Answer (score 0):

Where are the settings for Enabling Details logging? I can't find at xxx/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1